# resultado api azure diferente do resultado do meu local

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, microsoft-azure

Criei uma API C# no azure onde ela me retorna um array passando os seguintes paramentos:

```
tccapiwebservice.azurewebsites.net/api/Algoritimos/PostAlgoritimo?_funcobjetiva=5,00;3,50&_maxmin=true&_restricoes=1,5;1.1;0.0;1&_sinalres=2;2;2&_valoruni=400;150;300&_tipo=true
```

Essa versão é a mesma que esta rodando no meu local, só que quando passo os mesmos parâmetros para a API local ele me traz resultados diferentes, segue os mesmos:

**API azure (resultado inesperado)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**API local (resultado esperado)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei o porque estão dando resultados diferentes.

Comment: repare que o separador decimal no azure é `.` e no local é `,` se você não está tratando isso corretamente, certamente terá problemas

Comment: muito obrigado, era exatamente isso! Para arrumar eu coloquei no meu webconfig a tag globalization como padrão culture pt-BR!

Answer (score 1):

Verifique a configuração de `culture` pois no azure o separador decimal está o ponto (`.`) e local está vírgula (`,`).

Como nos parâmetro você passa valores com separadores, pode estar acontecendo erro ao tratar esses valores.

Como informado pelo colega, ele resolveu colocando a tag `globalization` no `web.config` como padrão PT-BR